# how to generate {8,3} regular graphs for large number of vertices

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, graph-theory

I want to generate regular graph of {8,3} tiling in the form of adjacency matrices for large number of vertices say n=10000. can somebody help me with some source code of doing that.

I am able to generate tiling on poincare disk. but not able to find the adjacency matrix for large number of vertices.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: from hypertiling import HyperbolicTiling
p = 8
q = 3
nlayers = 5

T = HyperbolicTiling(p,q,nlayers)

from hypertiling.graphics.plot import plot_tiling

import matplotlib.cm as cmap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colors = np.random.rand(len(T))

plot_tiling(T, colors, cmap=cmap.RdBu, edgecolor="k", linewidth=0.2);
plt.show()

Comment: how i can get assure that the tiling is regular and how to write its adjacency matrix?